# No keepalive sent from client for 1171 seconds (>=180)

Tags: sensu

I have a setup of sensu core(single server with muliple clients).
I am facing the issue like - `'No keepalive sent from client for 7807 seconds (>=180)'` from multiple clients though they instances are alive.

I've checked the time in both client and server instances. It does not have much variations(only in secs). I tried to install ntpdate on both instances.

```
[root@client-machine user]# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
31 Aug 14:07:50 ntpdate[14158]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting

[root@server-machine:/home/user]# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
31 Aug 14:08:04 ntpdate[29031]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

At intermittently, status in uchiwa shows green for this client-machine and it automatically goes to RED for further checks

Kindly advise to get rid of this problem!

Comment: would you be able to show logs from both your sensu server and client?, logs for sensu-server, sensu-client would be really helpful

Comment: {"timestamp":"2018-09-24T10:16:22.299886+0000","level":"info","message":"publishing check result","payload":{"client":"freshcaller-ci","check":{"command":"/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/check-disk-usage.rb -I / -w 80 -c 90","occurrences":5,"name":"check-disks","issued":1537784182,"executed":1537784182,"duration":0.069,"output":"CheckDisk OK: All disk usage under 80% and inode usage under 85%\n","status":0}}}

Comment: above one is sensu-client log. this one is server log:  {"timestamp":"2018-09-24T10:24:22.295463+0000","level":"info","message":"publishing check result","payload":{"client":"sensu-server1","check":{"command":"/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/check-disk-usage.rb -I / -w 80 -c 90","occurrences":5,"name":"check-disks","issued":1537784662,"interval":60,"subscribers":["runway"],"executed":1537784662,"duration":0.062,"output":"CheckDisk OK: All disk usage under 80% and inode usage under 85%\n","status":0}}}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by first setting the timezone and then installing the following packages

```
date
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Dublin
yum -y install chrony
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal for your answer. I just found the rootcause of the issue as sensu-server service was running in multiple instances. Stopped those services except in server machine. Now everything looks great!